# Trying to make update to WebSphere MQ Queue atomic

Tags: c#, queue, websphere, atomic

I am trying to make an update to a WebSphere Queue atomic and running into the following problem: Once the _outPutQueue.Put() method is called an MQ Exception is thrown that simply says "MQRC_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED." This happens because I've wrapped the method call inside a  using (CommittableTransaction) block. If I take the method call outside of the block, it works fine. Is this a simply a limitation of writing to a Queue inside C#?

```
 using (CommittableTransaction transScope = new CommittableTransaction())
 {
      CommittableTransaction.Current = transScope;


      try
      {                        

          foreach (string agentItem in qSqlContents.Values)
          {
                // Define a WebSphere MQ message, writing some text in UTF format
                MQMessage mqMessage = new MQMessage();
                mqMessage.Write(StrToByteArray(agentItem));

                // Specify the message options
                MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

                // MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT = provide transaction support for the Put.
                pmo.Options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;

                // Put the message on the queue
                _outputQueue.Put(mqMessage, pmo);
          }                       
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
          transScope.Rollback();                        
       }
       finally
       {
          transScope.Commit();                        
       }
 }
```

As requested here is the full exception information:

```
MQRC_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED
Exception | System.Exception
     base {object} | object 
Non-Public members | 
     _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, there are a few tweaks which will speed things up in general, not 100% sure this will fix your issue, but it may help me diagnose it...

```
// Specify the message options
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

// MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT = provide transaction support for the Put.
pmo.Options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;
CommittableTransaction transScope = new CommittableTransaction();
CommittableTransaction.Current = transScope;    

try
{                            
    foreach (string agentItem in qSqlContents.Values)
    {
        // Define a WebSphere MQ message, writing some text in UTF format
        MQMessage mqMessage = new MQMessage();
        mqMessage.Write(StrToByteArray(agentItem));

        // Put the message on the queue
        _outputQueue.Put(mqMessage, pmo);
    }                       
}
catch (Exception)
{
    transScope.Rollback();                        
}
finally
{
    _outputQueue.close();
    transScope.Commit(); 
    transScope.Dispose();                       
}
```

Comment: I don't have my dev machine to test out why you're having this issue, could you try my updated code above?  Check to see if it's the first run of outputQueue.Put that is causing the error, the second, third etc and let me know.  Hopefully this will solve your issue though.  using statements pretty much just call dispose on the object anyway...

Comment: Just ran this (copied and pasted) and it throws an exception the first time _outputQueue.Put() gets called. The loop does not make it to a second iteration.

Comment: Can you update your post to include the full exception information?

Comment: Done. The exception in all caps is the MQException VS catches. The rest are in the white dialog box that appears next to the "catch (Exception)" line.